# Using term or terms with one value in Elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am querying an Elasticsearch index using the values of a field. Sometimes, I have to extract all the documents having a field set to exactly one value; Some other times  I have to retrieve all the documents having a field, set with one of the values in a list of values.

The latter use case contains the former. Can I use a single query using the `terms` construct?

```
POST /_search
{
    "query": {
        "terms" : { "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"]}
    }
}
```

Or, in cases I know I need to search only for a unique value, it is better to use the `term` construct?

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" } 
    }
}
```

Which approach is better regarding performance? Does Elasticsearch perform any optimization if the value in the `terms` construct is unique?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/term-vs-terms-filter/15533). Terms query is automatically cached while term query is not . So, the next you run the same query, the took time for query for execution will be faster. So if you have a case where you need to run the same query again and again, terms query is a good choice. If not, there is not much of difference between the two.

Comment: Can you make your answer self-contained? Links on the internet are not reliable regarding availability :)